# Can I scp to localhost while logged in to remotehost

Tags: ssh, scp, mobile-phone

I am logged to my remote host via ssh. On my localhost I cannot issue
   scp remote:. /myfile. 
Because I am on a phone and I lack a terminal to do that.

Can I issue something like, while logged in to remote,

```
User@remote: $ scp myfile myimplicitlocalhost
```

This would be a sort of reverse tunnel. Can this be done without additional settings apart from my current key being on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no.

Long answer - to use scp you would need a running server on the localhost, and also a publicly accessible IP address. You say you're from a phone, this means you 99% don't have the first, and most likely neither the second. The scp won't know where to connect, and also as there won't be anyone answering him from your localhost will fail any way even if it knew where to connect.

As you are saying you're from a phone, and I assume it's a smartphone, you can try to search your application store for some SCP-compatible file manager and run it as a second application (as most smartphones theese days support multitasking), effectively switching between the two to either use plain ssh or transfer files.

Comment: Well, it would be possible if a ssh server is running on both machines and there is no NAT in between. But this is unlikely on a phone.